# Solving for a unknown in a equation at an uncertain answer. Solve for f:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am asked to solve for f in:

$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{f}$

The least common denominator is $pqf$

So, if I multiple everything by the lcd I get:

$pqf\frac{1}{p}+pqf\frac{1}{q}=pqf\frac{1}{f}$

Then if I cancel out variables common factors of each I get:

$qf+pf=pq$ which I can write as $f(p+q)=pq$

Now I just want $f$ on it's own so:

$f=\frac{pq}{q+p}$

Is this correct?

Because looking at the initial equation, I "feel" like it should just be $f=p+q$ since it's all expressed as $1/x$.

Is my solution for $f$ correct? If not, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=\frac{p+q}{pq}$$ so $$f=\frac{pq}{p+q}$$